# Powerpoint on monitor

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a monitor plugged into a lap top (so I can see what I am doing).  Sometimes, I must hit something and the monitor goes blank but I can see what I am working on on my lap top.  I can never remember what I do to get it back or what I do to loose it.  Can you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

When using presenter mode, i.e. the presentation runs on one screen (or the projector) and you can see your notes on the laptop screen, you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to blacken the presentation screen. Or you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to make the presentation screen go white.

To get the slide back, just hit the same key combination again.